# Hadoop fs lookup for block size?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In Hadoop fs how to lookup the block size for a particular file?

I was primarily interested in a command line, something like:

```
hadoop fs ... hdfs://fs1.data/...
```

But it looks like that does not exist. Is there a Java solution?

Comment: Do you mean the particular file size?

Comment: Nope, block size. The default is HDFS block size is 64MB and it can be changed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems hadoop fs doesn't have options to do this.

But hadoop fsck could.

You can try this

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fsck /path/to/file -files -blocks
```

Answer (score 46):

The `fsck` commands in the other answers list the blocks and allow you to see the number of blocks. However, to see the actual block size in bytes with no extra cruft do:

```
hadoop fs -stat %o /filename
```

Default block size is:

```
hdfs getconf -confKey dfs.blocksize
```

#### Details about units

The units for the block size are not documented in the `hadoop fs -stat` command, however, looking at the [source line](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/c6330f22a5e5c2370bab885f9bea4bf8f5e9cf44/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/shell/Stat.java#L125) and the [docs for the method it calls](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html#getBlockSize--) we can see it uses bytes and cannot report block sizes over about 9 exabytes.

The units for the `hdfs getconf` command may not be bytes. It returns whatever string is being used for `dfs.blocksize` in the configuration file. (This is seen in the source for the [final function](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/c6330f22a5e5c2370bab885f9bea4bf8f5e9cf44/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.java#L1126) and [its indirect caller](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/c6330f22a5e5c2370bab885f9bea4bf8f5e9cf44/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/tools/GetConf.java#L174))

Comment: Can you provide the unit of the output by the provided command.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be doable with:

```
hadoop fsck /filename -blocks
```

but I get *Connection refused*

Comment: I have done test, yes, it works. You mean connection refused or permission refused?

Answer (score 1):

Try to code below

```
path=hdfs://a/b/c

size=`hdfs dfs -count ${path} | awk '{print $3}'`
echo $size
```

Answer (score 0):

For displaying the actual block size of the existing file within HDFS I used:

```
[pety@master1 ~]$ hdfs dfs -stat %o /tmp/testfile_64
67108864
```