# How to determine number of buckets in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

How to determine the number of buckets for coulmn in hive? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730567/total-number-of-buckets-in-a-hive-table
Hope this link helps!

Comment: Did you mean determine number of buckets once a clustered tables in created?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we decide the total no. of buckets for a hive table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730567/how-can-we-decide-the-total-no-of-buckets-for-a-hive-table)

Comment: lalita please eloborate your question with examples. it should be verifiable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for bucket information on a partition use below command.

```
     DESCRIBE formatted part_table partition( partitionName)
```

Note you can get partition detail using  "show partitions part_table;"